# React generated documentation (.md file) and passing custom style to element inside component

Tags: css, reactjs, documentation

I wrote a React component called MyComponent and I need to write the .md file to generate the document describing its use.

The structure of the component inside the .jsx file is like this:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div> <img id="image-to-style" /> </div> 
        ); 
    }
}
```

The component automatically gives the style `margin-top: 40px` to the img element thanks to the .less file loaded in the entry file (not shown). However, this style does not appear in the generated doc (I know because the margin is off), so I have to apply it manually in the .md file.

The code in the .md file looks like this:

````
```jsx
const myImageStyle = {
  marginTop: '40px'
};

<MyComponent
    style={myImageStyle}
 />
```
````

What I'm trying to do here is to pass myImageStyle down to the img element inside my component.

For simplicity I didn't put in any properties in my minimum working component here.

I thought of adding a new style property to the actual .jsx component file just so it renders the same way in the generated doc than it does otherwise, but it seems hackish to me.

My question is: what is the best way to make the style apply to the img element inside my component in the generated documentation .md file?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out we really do have to import the .less file in the component.

Styles related to a component should be in a MyComponent.less file rather than a GenericStyleFileForAllComponentsBelowThisEntryFile.jsx. Then importing MyComponent.less in MyComponent.jsx is not hackish because MyComponent.less is not imported anywhere else.